# Multinomial Generation of Degree n

Tags: math

I'm basically looking for a summation function that will compute multinomials given the number of variables and a degree.

Example

```
2 Variables; 2 Degrees:

x^2+y^2+x*y+x+y+1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Language? How are you storing them? Details.

Comment: @Chris: Please ask in mathoverflow.net instead.

Comment: @Kenny: OOoooo didn't know such a thing existed. Thanks.

Comment: This is a programming questions and answer site, not math.

Comment: @Kenny: mathoverflow is not what you think; it's a site for professional mathematicians. A question like this would be closed immediately. This happens to be a valid programming question, and is more appropriate here.

Answer (score 4):

See Knuth *The Art of Computer Programming*, Vol. 4, Fascicle 3 for a comprehensive answer.

Short answer: it's enough to generate all multinomial expressions in n variables with degree *exactly* d. Then, for your problem, you can either put together the answers with degrees ≤d, or add a dummy variable "1".

The problem of generating all expressions with degree exactly d is thus simply one of generating all ordered partitions (i.e., all nonnegative integer solutions to x<sub>1</sub> + ... + x<sub>n</sub> = d), and this can be done with a simple backtracking algorithm. ("Depth-first search")

Answer (score 1):

Given N variables, and a maximum degree of D, you have an array of D slots to fill with all possible combinations of variables.

[_, _, ..., _, _]

You are allowed to fill the slots with any of the N variables any number <= D times total. Since multiplication is commutative, it suffices to not care about ordering of variables. As such, this problem is reduced to generating (1) partitions of an integer and (2) subsets of a set.

I hope this is at least a start to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This also seems to be a Dynamic programming variant of the 0-1 Knapsack problem. Here we would be interested in all possible leaves of the decision tree.